# Any applicable approach for the solution

Tags: volume

Water flows through circular pipe of crossection area 6.16cm² at uniform speed of 10cm/sec.At 6.00am,water starts  flowing through into empty rectangular tank of base area 3m².
If the tank is 1.2m high and has a hole at the bottom which water leaks at rate of 11.6cm³ per second, determine time at which tank will be filled.
In this problem,I have gotten the depth  of water in the tank  as 18.48cm.How can I  proceed from here.please help

Comment: You'll find you get a lot more help and fewer votes to close if you show that you've made an effort to do the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts on it.  What have you done?  What is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

- determine the net flow in the tank $Q=Q_{in}-Q_{out}$
- calculate the volume $V$ of the tank
- then time $t=\frac{V}{Q}$